# shuffle the array in actionscript -2

Tags: actionscript-2

For generating the bingo ticket generator I need the shuffling array .

When I press a button I should retrive the values from array (ex. `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`). I

If I retrive first five random value may be `2 5 7 4 8`. If press the button again then it should retrive other than previously retrived value (ex. `1 3 9 6 7`)

Comment: what have you done in this task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are allowed to modify your input but why not try something like this :

```
// passing your array as argument
// passing the total number you want to extract as argument
function getRandNumbers( a:Array, requested_numbers:Number ):Array
{
    // verify we don't request to much numbers
    if ( requested_numbers > a.length ) 
    {
       trace( "Not enought available numbers in array" );
       return null;
    }

    results_array = new Array(); // create our output array
    while( results_array.length < requested_numbers )
    {
       rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * a.length );
       results_array.push( a[rnd] );
       a.splice( rnd, 1 ); // remove the random result
    }

}
```

now you're sure your array will contain only non used numbers each time you will call getRandNumbers.